# on link hover display div when leave cursor form div and link hide div jquery

Tags: jquery

I have link and  on hover it should display the div when leave cursor form div and link it should hide div.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_div">2 items</a>
<div id="dropcart">contents</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#show_div").hover(function(){
      $("#dropcart").fadeIn();
     });                
 });

  </script>
```

Comment: Did you check my updated answer????

Answer (score 2):

Updated as per your comments:

```
$("#show_div").hover(function(){
     $("#dropcart").fadeIn();
});

$("#dropcart").mouseleave(function(){
    if($("#show_div").is(':hover') === false)
    $("#dropcart").fadeOut("fast"); 
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a57W6/4/)

Comment: wrong answer..its not working. you haven't understand my question.

Comment: when you will hove on dropcart div it disapears, i want that when hover on link its dipslay and hover on dropcart dive its still remain displayed. and when leave both link and this div. it must hide

Comment: Yes but when i hover on contents div its hide..it must display..when i leave mouse from link and this div it must hide.