# on link hover display div, which show on hover of that div and link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have link and on link hover display div when leave cursor form div and link hide div using jQuery. i have code for display it, how can i hide it while i leave cursor from these link and div.this is my html code.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_div">2 items</a>
 <div id="dropcart">contents</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#show_div").hover(function(){
       $("#dropcart").fadeIn();
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Why you people down vote my question.. :(

Comment: Are you asking this question ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148066/on-link-hover-dipslay-div-when-leave-cursor-form-div-and-link-hide-div-jquery/23148112?noredirect=1#comment35395726_23148112 check my answer there.

Comment: yes..no one give me proper answer.

Comment: if you provide fiddle that will be easy

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlainArif check my answer there with working fiddle.

Comment: @C-link its not working i have checked it. make a fiddle and send me..:)

Comment: Oooops! then check my answer here!!!!!

Comment: @C-link great work...thanks.. now please vote up my question.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#show_div").hover(function(){
     $("#dropcart").fadeIn();
});

$("#dropcart").mouseleave(function(){
    if($("#show_div").is(':hover') === false)
    $("#dropcart").fadeOut("fast"); 
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a57W6/4/)

Answer (score -3):

EDIT: (For the downvoters and OP)

I misunderstood the question.  My suggestion, then, would be to use timeouts.

```
.hover(function(){ clearTimeout(window["timeoutVar"]); $("#dropcart").fadeIn(); },function(){window["timeoutVar"]=setTimeout(function(){ $("#dropcart").fadeout(); },50);});
```

Then apply that `.hover` to the div, also.  That way, the div will fade out after a 50-millisecond delay IF the user does not hover over it, which will cancel the timeout (and prevent the fadeout).

Comment: you haven't understand my question, but when i hover on dropcart div it hide. it must remain show when i hover on div and link.-